# ASP .NET Core 6 Razor Pages: HttpContext.Session error

Tags: c#, razor-pages, asp.net-core-6.0

I am trying to develop a course selling application using ASP.NET  Core 6 Razor Pages, in which I have to implement a shopping cart. I am thinking of implementing this using sessions.

My code looks as follows:

Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie( options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/AccessForbidden");
    options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/AccessForbidden");
});

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseSession();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

ShoppingCart page code-behind:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session;

namespace WebApp.Pages
{
    [Authorize]
    public class ShoppingCartModel : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet()
        {
        }

        public void AddToCart(string courseId)
        {
            var cart = HttpContext.Session.Get<List<string>>("ShoppingCart");
            cart.Add(courseId);
            HttpContext.Session.Set("ShoppingCart", cart);
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment, I do not have a working page to implement the feature, it is just the functionality that I want to figure out, and for the line:

```
var cart = HttpContext.Session.Get<List<string>>("ShoppingCart");
```

I get this error:

> CS1929: 'ISession' does not contain a definition for 'Get' and the best extension method overload 'ConfigurationBinder.Get<List<string>>(IConfiguration, Action<BinderOptions>?)' requires a receiver of type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration'

What did I do wrong? Thanks!

Comment: [ASP.NET Core redesigned `Session`'s API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.isession.set?view=aspnetcore-7.0) ([compared to pre-2016 ASP.NET MVC `System.Web`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate?view=netframework-4.7.2)): you need to use `TryGetValue` and `Set` instead of `Get` and `Set`.

Comment: `options.LoginPath = new PathString("/AccessForbidden");` <-- I suspect you'll want to use a different URL path for `LoginPath`...

Comment: @Dai Based on his scenario he also can use `GetString` because he has complex object and each time he wants to get new ShoppingCart object once new items added. Extension method wound be th ideal solution here. Do you agree?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron No, I don't agree: we can't offer any concrete solutions because the OP hasn't laid-out exactly what their project requirements are (besides, using _only_ `String` values is just so very far removed from what's actually needed to build a functioning online shopping-cart system).

Comment: Okay got your point apart from solution, using `SessionExtension` method  [`in my test I have extracted shopping curt object`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS0l1.gif) like this way `var  cart = HttpContext.Session.GetComplexObjectSession<ShoppingCartObject>("ShoppingCart");` where though `ISession` I am setting session key as `session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));`